# Getting the closest match by shortest Euclidean distance to fill the NAs in R

Tags: r

I am trying to fill the NAs in the specific column, e.g. "c" by the closest match with shortest Euclidean distance in the values in other two columns, e.g. "a" and "b", i.e. I want to replace the na(i) in c with the one has minimum "(a-ai)^2 + (b-bi)^2".
I have written r code like this:

```
fillgroup = fillgroup %>%
  mutate(match = if_else(
    is.na(c)
    , which.min((fillgroup$a-a)^2 + (fillgroup$b-b)^2)
    , NA_real_
  )) %>%
  mutate(c = if_else(
    is.na(c)
    , fillgroup$c[match]
    , c
  ))
```

The problem now is that I could only get value 1 in column match, I thought the problem might be the second "a" in "(fillgroup$a-a)^2" starts from the first value in column a, which is not what I want(i want the a which in the same with the na value in c column).
Does someone have any idea how to fix this?

And another problem is that currently i haven't excluded the a and b which in the same row with the target na in c in the which.min comparison, which is absolutely a problem.

Edit:
the example data go like:

```
    > dput(head(fillgroup))

structure(c = c(0.00131, 0.02349, 0.00157, 0.00342, 
0.00484, 0.00203), a = c(1763L, 
    487L, 1560L, 1088L, 1519L, 1803L), b = c(685L, 1456L, 
    289L, 861L, 293L, 736L), match = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_)), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x7fb85780dce0>)
```

Comment: Please share some example data using `dput(head(fillgroup))`.

Comment: Hey, theres an option in KNN function which is based on euclidean distance to fill your NA'